# Comparing dictionary values swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries of type

```
[["OptionId": 824, "QuestionId": 208],
["OptionId": 810, "QuestionId": 205],
["OptionId": 1017, "QuestionId": 257],
["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 201],
["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 199],
["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 200]]
```

I have iterated through these values and extracted the dictionaries values as

```
["OptionId": 824, "QuestionId": 208]
["OptionId": 810, "QuestionId": 205]
["OptionId": 1017, "QuestionId": 257]
["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 201]
["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 199]
["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 200]
```

Now, I want to get the "QuestionId" for all those "OptionId" which are 0. How can I compare the dictionary key-value to zero? Thanks in advance.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for dictionary in arrayofDict {
    print(dictionary)
    if (dictionary["OptionId"] == 0) {
        print("option not selected")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have tried?

Comment: for dictionary in arrayofDict {
         print(dictionary)
         if (dictionary["OptionId"] == 0) {
                    print("option not selected")
                }
            }   
   }

This is what I have tried.

Answer (score 5):

A "filter + map" operation can be done with a single `flatMap`
call (avoiding the creation of an intermediate array). In your case:

```
let arrayofDict = [["OptionId": 824, "QuestionId": 208],
                 ["OptionId": 810, "QuestionId": 205],
                 ["OptionId": 1017, "QuestionId": 257],
                 ["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 201],
                 ["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 199],
                 ["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 200]]

let notSelected = arrayofDict.flatMap { $0["OptionId"] == 0 ? $0["QuestionId"] : nil }

print(notSelected) // [201, 199, 200]
```

Comment: For me, it is kind of a rule that: if `filter` & `map`, then `flatMap`, do you think it's always right? :)

Comment: @AhmadF: You *can* always combine it, but I am reluctant to say that one always should do it. With complicated/nested filters/maps it could for example decrease the code readability. Using `lazy` is another option to avoid the creation of an intermediate array.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use filter on the array of dictionaries to get the dictionaries, where `OptionId` is 0, then use `flatMap` to get the corresponding non-optional `QuestionId`s.

```
let questionsDict: [[String:Any]] = [["OptionId": 824, "QuestionId": 208],["OptionId": 810, "QuestionId": 205], ["OptionId": 1017, "QuestionId": 257], ["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 201], ["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 199], ["OptionId": 0, "QuestionId": 200]]
let filtered = questionsDict.filter{($0["OptionId"] as? Int) == 0}.flatMap{$0["QuestionId"] as? Int} //contains 201,200,199
```

Comment: I get an error  "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'Int'"

Comment: @Dyana check my updated answer. Your dictionary wasn't casted to have `Int` values, so you need to cast the values to `Int` first.

Comment: but my dictionary contains strings too... that is is reason it was casted to [string:Any]

Comment: Well your example only contained `Int`s. Anyways, my answer works on `[String:Any]` since the last edit, so you can use it safely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   arr.filter {return $0["OptionId"] == 0}.flatMap {return $0["QuestionId"]}return $0["QuestionId"]}
```

Comment: There is no need to safely unwrap the optional dictionary value, `Optional` conforms to the `Equatable` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter as follows:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "OptionId == %@",NSNumber.init(value: 0))
let filteredArray = arrayofDict.filter { searchPredicate.evaluate(with: $0) };
let result = filteredArray.flatMap{$0["QuestionId"]}
```